# Dragdealer slider adding values together

Tags: jquery, html, dragdealer-js

I am trying to use the Dragdealer to create a small game but keep getting my formatting wrong. I want to add the two values together and ensure that they are still in synchronisation and are therefore within 20 places of each other.

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="content-scroller1">
            <div id="content-scroller1" class="dragdealer">
                <div class="handle red-bar" style="-webkit-perspective: 1000px; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);">
                <span class="value1"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="content-scroller2">
            <div id="content-scroller2" class="dragdealer">
                <div class="handle red-bar" style="-webkit-perspective: 1000px; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);">
                <span class="value2"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <input type="button" value="Get slider value" id="button1" />


    </div>



new Dragdealer('content-scroller1', {
  horizontal: false,
  vertical: true,
  yPrecision: 100,
  animationCallback: function(x, y) {
  $('.content-scroller1 .value1').text(Math.round(y * 100));
  }
});

new Dragdealer('content-scroller2', {
  horizontal: false,
  vertical: true,
  y: 1,
  yPrecision: 100,
  animationCallback: function(x, y) {
  $('.content-scroller2 .value2').text(Math.round(y * 100));

  }
});

var syncTest = function () {
  var posOne = parseInt($('.content-scroller1 .value1').text());
  var posTwo = parseInt($('.content-scroller2 .value2').text());

if ((posOne + posTwo > 90) && (posOne + posTwo < 110)); {
    alert($('yes'));
  }



};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span class="value">83</span>` doesn't have the attribute - value.

Change `val()` to `text()`

```
var posOne = parseInt($('.content-scroller1 .value1').text());
var posTwo = parseInt($('.content-scroller2 .value2').text());
```

Comment: Is that everything as it doesn't seem to work?
The span class value gets inserted via the javascript.

Comment: Thanks the jsfiddle helped!